# Using a position variable of a javascript object to find related attributes

Tags: javascript, foreach, javascript-objects

This code finds the position of "AL" in a javascript object and then searches the position of "AL" to find other attributes related to "AL", such as width.

Why is this code returning the width of the last item in the object, instead of the width of "AL"?

I can successfully code position `[0]`but I want the position coded as variable `[z]`

```js
myObj = {
  "type":"A",
  "info": [
    { "item":"1", "properties":{ "id":"AL", "height": "25", width: "50" } },
    { "item":"2", "properties":{ "id":"PO", "height": "30", width: "40" } },
    { "item":"3", "properties":{ "id":"RA", "height": "20", width: "100" } }
  ]
}


myObj.info.forEach(function(e, z) {
  if (e.properties.id == "AL") document.getElementById("position").innerHTML = z;
  document.getElementById("width").innerHTML = myObj.info[z].properties.width;
});
```

```html
<p>Position in object:<span id="position"></span></p>

<p>Width:<span id="width"></span></p>
```

Comment: You're using `forEach`, and you run `document.getElementById("width").innerHTML` unconditionally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your if statement with a block of code so that the last statement will be executed inside the if statement

```js
myObj = {
  "type":"A",
  "info": [
    { "item":"1", "properties":{ "id":"AL", "height": "25", width: "50" } },
    { "item":"2", "properties":{ "id":"PO", "height": "30", width: "40" } },
    { "item":"3", "properties":{ "id":"RA", "height": "20", width: "100" } }
  ]
}


myObj.info.forEach(function(e, z) {
  if (e.properties.id == "AL") {
    document.getElementById("position").innerHTML = z;
    document.getElementById("width").innerHTML = myObj.info[z].properties.width;
  }
  
});
```

```html
<p>Position in object:<span id="position"></span></p>

<p>Width:<span id="width"></span></p>
```

Comment: Thank you, I really missed that.